# Cron Job to Clear Cache in EE3

Tags: cron

I have an ExpressionEngine 3 site that the client doesn't want to upgrade but we need to clear the cache weekly. I'd like to set up a cron job to do this.

Is this possible? If so how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this Cron Clean Cache addon:

https://expressionengine.com/add-ons/cron-clean-cache

https://expressionengine.com/add-ons/cron

Easy to implement and working fine !

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bash or php script, external from EE, that flushes the /user/cache/* folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you'd delete cache every Sunday at 12:00 AM.

Run crontab -e

Define:

0 0 * * 0 rm /path/to/user/cache/*